# Calculation in handsontable

Tags: javascript, calculated-columns, handsontable

I want to concatenate values from a handsontable grid. So, I found something on jsfiddle and I'm trying to adapt it in my case.
Here is the link :

http://jsfiddle.net/9onuhpn7/4/

So I have 3 columns A,B,C and I'm trying to concatenate them and display the result in "SUM" column, but it's not working.

As I said, it's a code that I took from another guy and I don't understand this line `if (changes[i][1] === 3) {`and if I take it off, it doesn't work anymore. If someone can tell me what's the purpose of that.

Someone can help me please ?

Comment: As far as I can tell (I'm not a handsontable expert), that line has a double function: it does not execute if the 3rd column is edited (changes[i] = [row,col,oldvalue,newvalue], so changes[i][1] contains the column being changed) and also makes sure changes are not recursive, because `hot.setDataAtCell(0, 3, value, 'changed');` seems to trigger the beforechange as well.

Comment: @Me.Name So, the calculation will happens only if the second cell is changed ?

Comment: Not entirely, it will happen if the info of cell being changed is not the 3rd index column, so in this case it will happen for columns with index 0,1 and 2. Note though, that since `beforeChange` is used in combination with a live `getDataAtCell`, the values for sum will always be a version behind. Done some fiddling, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9onuhpn7/7/ would work provided the sum column is the last column

Comment: Oops, didn't notice your question was answered in the meantime, first time SO notifications didn't work for me haha.

Comment: @Me.Name Your answer works too, I keep it ;) Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you took is a bit weird. I updated it a bit to better suit what you're looking for.

(PS: I'm not a Handsontable user)

Basically, the problem seems to be that you're listening to a change event, and in this change event, you're doing some changes. This may lead you to infinite event loop.

The line

```
if(changes[i][1] === 3)
```

is just here to prevent this loop. Basically, if the change occurred on the 'SUM' cell which is at coords [i,1], then, we do not want to trigger the change again (as it just happened).

Take a look at this code: http://jsfiddle.net/9onuhpn7/6/

When calling setDataAtCell(), you can associate a name to the change.
This name will be the 2nd parameter of the afterChange listener.

You simply have to use a condition on the source name of the event to trigger it or not.

Comment: I also took the liberty of changing the 'beforeChange' event to 'afterChange'. It seems more natural if the update is done right after finishing editing a cell.